# how to pass parameters between hbs files in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

i have created an application using ember.js.
here i couldn't get the parameter value passed from tasks.hbs to subtasks.hbs.how could i get parameter value passed from tasks.hbs in subtasks.hbs and print it in subtasks.hbs?

app/templates/tasks.hbs:

```
{{outlet}}
<h1>Tasks</h1>
{{#each model as |task|}}
    <div class="well">
        <h4>{{#link-to 'tasks.edit' task.id}}{{task.title}}{{/link-to}}</h4>
        <small>Created: {{format-date task.created}}</small><br>
        <small>Due: {{format-date task.date}}</small>
        <h5>Priority: {{task.priority}}</h5>
        <p>{{task.description}}</p>
        <button {{action 'deleteTask' task.id}} class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button><hr>

        {{#link-to 'subtasks.subnew' task.id}}<button  class="btn btn-primary">Create SubTask</button>{{/link-to}}

        {{#link-to 'subtasks' task.id}}<button class="btn btn-primary">Show SubTasks</button>{{/link-to}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

app/templates/subtasks.hbs:

```
{{outlet}}
<h1>SubTasks</h1>
<h2>{{task_id}}</h2>
{{#each model as |subtask|}}
<h1>{{subtask.id}}</h1>
{{#if model.id subtask.tno}}
    <div class="well">
        <h4>{{#link-to 'subtasks.subedit' subtask.id}}{{subtask.subtitle}}{{/link-to}}</h4>
        <small>Created: {{format-date subtask.subcreated}}</small><br>
        <small>Due: {{format-date subtask.subdate}}</small>
        <h5>Priority: {{subtask.subpriority}}</h5>
        <p>{{subtask.subdescription}}</p>
        <button {{action 'deleteSubTask' subtask.id}} class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </div>
{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

app/routes/tasks.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(){
        return this.store.findAll('task');
    }
});
```

app/routes/subtasks.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(){
        return this.store.findAll('subtask');
    }
});
```

router.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('tasks', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('edit', {path: '/edit/:task_id'});
  });
  this.route('subtasks', {path: '/subtasks/:task_id'}, function() {
    this.route('subnew', {path: '/subnew/:task_id'});
    this.route('subedit', {path: '/subedit/:subtask_id'});
  });
});

export default Router;
```

Answer (score 0):

You already defined `task_id` as a dynamic segment for subtask. So you need to extract it from `params` argument in the subtask's model hook. And then return this `task_id` from the model hook.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const {
  RSVP
} = Ember;

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(params){
        return RSVP.hash({
          subtasks: this.store.findAll('subtask'),
          taskId: params.taskId
        });
    }
});
```

After this, you can access it in the subtask.hbs like this:

```
{{model.taskId}}
```

- [Ember guides about dynamic segment](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_dynamic-models)
- [route model hook API](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.Route/methods/model?anchor=model)